# How to get the properties of object that is displayed to the console as object object

Tags: angular, typescript, oop

I have a function like this.

```
monthChanger(event) {
                  console.log('monthChanged.............'+event); }
```

which is used in template as

```
  <ion-calendar [(ngModel)]="date"
                  (change)="onChange($event)"
                  [options]="options"
                  type="string"
                  format="YYYY-MM-DD"
                  readonly="true"
                  (monthChange)="monthChanger($event)"

                  >
    </ion-calendar>linked to template like this.
```

The console is showing like this only

[image]

How can i access the attributes inside object.Please help me.I mean the data fields and properties.

Answer (score 3):

```
  console.log('monthChanged.............'+JSON.stringify(event));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can separate your objects and comments with `,` : [`console.log()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log)

Example :

```
console.log('monthChanged.............', event);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you do not need to do these extra marking for angular console. Since it is in browser, by default, it will show line number on the right. you can just do `console.log(event)`. Usually, the data is stored under `event.target`

Answer (score -1):

You can pass multiple arguments with console.log function and each parameter will be listed separately.

```
console.log('Month changed', event);
```